# If ListView Column "x" Contains "value"

Tags: c#, listview

This is embedded in another loop, and well, it's pretty slow.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
for(int i=0;i< listView.Items.Count;i++)
{
    if(listView.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text == "asdf")
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: We can't be sure, we need to see a the container loop, to see if it can be improved

Comment: Chuck, the string "asdf" is just being switched with different values in the container loop.

Comment: How many items does this loop cover and how many items does the outer loop go through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there's a *nicer* way to do it:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
{
    if (item.SubItems[3].Text == "asdf")
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

Or you could use LINQ:

```
var query = listView.Items
                    .Cast<ListViewItem>()
                    .Where(item => item.SubItems[3].Text == "asdf");
foreach (var item in query)
{
    ...
}
```

I doubt that that will be faster though...

Does your outer loop change the `listView`? If not, could you do the query once and reuse the results in the outer loop?

Comment: Nice, let me implement that (if there's no better suggestion).

Comment: Soo, as Skeet said, this is a NICER way not a FASTER way. You have to provide more details to get the best answer

Comment: Is this supposed to work in WPF?  I don't have `SubItems` in intellisense on `item`.

Comment: @vapcguy: No, it's WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone runs across this using WPF, you don't get `.SubItems` on `item` when you use `foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)`.  Instead, I found I could just use `DataRowView` and get the value of the cell that way:

```
foreach (DataRowView drv in listView.Items)
{
    if (drv.Row[3].ToString() == "asdf")
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You do have to add a `using System.Data;` statement at the top of your class to use it.  I found it worked in WPF, and it might in other areas (i.e. WinForms), as well.